# Fake data in draft report

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I'm designing a report draft in ssrs to show to the business so they can make decisions about lay-out/data ordering and grouping and what fields to leave out or add to the report.

For this I don't want to focus on layout and not waste any time and effort on writing queries to fill the various tables and lists.

Does the ssrs designer somehow allow to keep my focus on the layout instead of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there's nothing built into SSRS to do this. There's a few tricks that come to mind though that you could do yourself to minimize time spent on creating mock data sets. Here's some I could come up with:

1. Use **existing Views** from your database for the datasets, that are structurally close to the datasets you'd create when the draft's been approved.
2. Use a **different (sample) database**, for example Adventureworks, and pick a View or sample query that's analogous to the data you'll be using for the final report.
3. (hack-warning! :D) **Use MS Excel to mock** a dataset, import it into a temporary table (e.g. with the SSMS import task), and just do `SELECT * FROM _importtable_` in the dataset.
4. **Write a fake query yourself**, but only pay attention to the first bit: do the `SELECT`, and skip everything from `FROM`. Combine it with a few `UNION`s to get some more data. For example create this dataset:

---

```sql
SELECT 1 AS UserId, 'John' AS Usr, 883 AS OrdersPlaced, '2012-05-16' AS OrderDate
UNION 
SELECT 1, 'John', 503, '2012-05-17'
UNION 
SELECT 2, 'Marcus', 503, '2012-05-16'
-- etc
```

Comment: I used your last suggestion, but created a table variable, then inserted some records and selected * from the table. It's close enough to my target without becoming too chaotic :)